# how can i add javafx.util.Pair to project compiled with jdk11.0.2?

Tags: javafx, java-11

Can not change the JDK, tried downloading `javafx.jar` and it did not work either. what should I do?

Comment: JavaFX is no longer part of the JDK. Read the OpenJFX [docs](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) on how to get started with JavaFX 11

Comment: Is `Pair` is the only javafx class used in your project?

Answer (score 15):

You can replace `javafx.util.Pair` (using `import javafx.util.Pair`) by `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` (using `import java.util.AbstractMap`) if it is the only class from javafx